# Read json file with jquery in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to readed json file in jquery with javascript. What is my wrong with this code

```js
$(function() {
  var new4 = [];
  $.getJSON('new4.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.new4, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.FirstName + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + f.LastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.EmailAddress + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.City + "</td>" + "</tr>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
      }
      ss);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
      <table id="userdata" border="2">
        <thead>
          <th>FirstName</th>
          <th>LastName</th>
          <th>EmailAddress</th>
          <th>City</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And my json codes

```
{
   "person": [
       {
           "firstName": "Clark",
           "lastName": "Kent",
           "Email Address": "Reporter",
           "City": 20
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Bruce",
           "lastName": "Wayne",
           "Email Address": "Playboy",
           "City": 30
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Peter",
           "lastName": "Parker",
           "Email Address": "Photographer",
           "City": 40
       }
   ]
}
```

For source, I download a jquery file fromwebsite to my folder.

I added this picture because of source is very important about json and I want to be sure my way is ture for create a html.

When I start html there is not data as shown in picture
[image: Output of html]

Comment: What error message you getting this time?

Comment: Actually nothing. Html opens but there is not a array or someting which inculude json file. When I start, just shown html file without information that given with json.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your AJAX request is working, there are several syntax problems in your code.

- You have a random `ss` before the `$.each()` closing brace
- You're looping over `data.new4` which doesn't exist. You need to loop over the `data.person` array
- The property names you're using do not match those in the object. Note that JS is case sensitive.
- You need to use bracket notation to access the `'Email Address'` property as it contains a space - or better still change it to match the format of the other properties, ie. `emailAddress`. The same should be done for `City` too.
- While not an error, you don't need to append string literals together, just put them in the same string.

With those fixes in place your code should work:

```js
var data = {
    "person": [{
        "firstName": "Clark",
        "lastName": "Kent",
        "Email Address": "Reporter",
        "City": 20
    }, {
        "firstName": "Bruce",
        "lastName": "Wayne",
        "Email Address": "Playboy",
        "City": 30
    }, {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Parker",
        "Email Address": "Photographer",
        "City": 40
    }]
}

//$.getJSON('new4.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
        var tblRow = "<tr><td>" + person.firstName + "</td><td>" + person.lastName + "</td><td>" + person['Email Address'] + "</td><td>" + person.City + "</td></tr>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
    });
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
        <table id="userdata" border="2">
            <thead>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>EmailAddress</th>
                <th>City</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also note that all of the above errors can be found by checking the console in your browser. This can generally be accessed by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for Your interest. That way works in same html but I will take json file from folder as this json folder will update always. If I take json file from a folder how can I update my codes. I wrote new4.json because this is which json file in folder. According to your codes How can I get json codes from out side. And I tried that codes here. https://jsfiddle.net/b5fr55qy/ but when I take this code on notepad++ they don't work.

Comment: This is a simplified version of your code. I only included the data in the answer as I can't make an AJAX request here. Just uncomment the `$.getJSON` lines.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly following code will solve your issue.

Please change your .each function with this

```
$.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
  var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f["Email Address"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.City + "</td>" + "</tr>"
  $(tblRow).appendTo('body');
});
```

```js
var data = {
   "person": [
       {
           "firstName": "Clark",
           "lastName": "Kent",
           "Email Address": "Reporter",
           "City": 20
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Bruce",
           "lastName": "Wayne",
           "Email Address": "Playboy",
           "City": 30
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Peter",
           "lastName": "Parker",
           "Email Address": "Photographer",
           "City": 40
       }
   ]
}

$.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
  var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f["Email Address"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.City + "</td>" + "</tr>"
  $(tblRow).appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: Note that `f.EmailAddress` will result in undefined.